# Android Text to Speech set Language

Tags: android

I don't have any special package installed beside the packages for the latest API in SDK.
I have a string with several words in Portuguese (Portugal) and I want to make the phone read that in Portuguese, but it seems that is an english tts engine reading Portuguese because its sounding really bad...

My code:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("pt_BR");
tts.setLanguage(loc);
```

Is it needed to install any extra package? Engine or w/e in my phone/eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

TTS supports: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish.

Comment: So there's no way to put it on Portuguese? Installing anything extra or  something?

Answer (score -1):

Set the Locale parameter as follows:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("pt", "BR");
```

Not all devices supports Portuguese.